# Order an array of objects by child array of objects max date

Tags: javascript

I am building up a simple messaging system and would like to reorder my conversations after a new message has been sent.

I would like to sort the array of conversations based on the maximum date from the message array.

Here is the structure of the objects I am working with
I have tried reducing the messages and then sorting but i'm not sure if there is a better solution for this

```
[
    {
        "conversationId": "3",
        "conversationTitle": "title 1",
        "messages": [
            {
                "content": "Message 1",
                "messageSent": "2020-05-11"
            },
            {
                "content": "Message 2",
                "messageSent": "2020-05-09"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "conversationId": "2",
        "conversationTitle": "title 2",
        "messages": [
                        {
                "content": "Message 1",
                "messageSent": "2020-05-11"
            },
            {
                "content": "Message 2",
                "messageSent": "2020-05-09"
            },            {
                "content": "Message 3",
                "messageSent": "2020-05-08"
            }
        ]
    }
    {
        "conversationId": "1",
        "conversationTitle": "title 3",
        "messages": [
                        {
                "content": "Message 1",
                "messageSent": "2020-05-07"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: what is the output you expected?

Comment: "*I have tried reducing the messages and then sorting*" - please show us that solution, otherwise we cannot advise you how (or whether) to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

[Lodash](http://lodash.com/) is really helpful for these kinds of problems. This sorts the conversations from newest to oldest based on all message dates (I edited some dates):

```js
const conversations = [
    {
        "conversationId": "3",
        "conversationTitle": "title 1",
        "messages": [
            {
                "content": "Message 1",
                "messageSent": "2020-05-11"
            },
            {
                "content": "Message 2",
                "messageSent": "2020-05-09"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "conversationId": "2",
        "conversationTitle": "title 2",
        "messages": [
                        {
                "content": "Message 1",
                "messageSent": "2020-05-13"
            },
            {
                "content": "Message 2",
                "messageSent": "2020-05-09"
            },            {
                "content": "Message 3",
                "messageSent": "2020-05-08"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "conversationId": "1",
        "conversationTitle": "title 3",
        "messages": [
                        {
                "content": "Message 1",
                "messageSent": "2020-05-15"
            }
        ]
    }
];

const sortedConversations = _.orderBy(conversations, function(conversation) {
  return _.max(_.map(conversation.messages, 'messageSent'));
}, 'desc');

console.log(sortedConversations)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what you want here is basically want to show the messages of a particular conversaiton either in ascending or descending.

So rather than reordering the whole JSON as and when new message comes in, you could try to add that particular message inside conversation with different methods like PUSH, SHIFT, UNSHIFT, POP which are inbuilt methods.
Refer this - [Link](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1796-javascript-array-methods-unshift-shift-push-and-pop.htm)

If you want to still reorder then you could probably do something like this snippet below -

```
arr.forEach((obj) => {
    obj.messages = obj.messages.sort(function(a,b){
        return (new Date(a.messageSent)) - (new Date(b.messageSent));
    });
});
```

Or as suggested by other users, you can use third party libraries like lodash, underscore etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try a sort, like this:

```js
const conversations = [{
    "conversationId": "3",
    "conversationTitle": "title 1",
    "messages": [{
        "content": "Message 1",
        "messageSent": "2020-05-11"
      },
      {
        "content": "Message 2",
        "messageSent": "2020-05-09"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "conversationId": "2",
    "conversationTitle": "title 2",
    "messages": [{
        "content": "Message 1",
        "messageSent": "2020-05-11"
      },
      {
        "content": "Message 2",
        "messageSent": "2020-05-09"
      }, {
        "content": "Message 3",
        "messageSent": "2020-05-08"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "conversationId": "1",
    "conversationTitle": "title 3",
    "messages": [{
      "content": "Message 1",
      "messageSent": "2020-05-07"
    }]
  }
]

const findLatestMessage = (messages) => {
  return new Date(Math.max.apply(null, messages.map(function(e) {
    return new Date(e.messageSent);
  })))
}

const sortByLatestMessage = (conversations) => {
  return conversations.sort((a, b) => {
    const aLatest = findLatestMessage(a.messages)
    const bLatest = findLatestMessage(b.messages)
    return aLatest < bLatest ? -1 : aLatest === bLatest ? 0 : 1
  })
}

const sorted = sortByLatestMessage(conversations)

console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to sort it. You can first `map` the data by reordering the dates in `messages` array after that apply sort on the recieved result. Here is how you can achive it.

```js
var data = [ { "conversationId": "3", "conversationTitle": "title 1", "messages": [ { "content": "Message 1", "messageSent": "2020-05-11" }, { "content": "Message 2", "messageSent": "2020-05-09" } ] }, { "conversationId": "2", "conversationTitle": "title 2", "messages": [ { "content": "Message 1", "messageSent": "2020-05-13" }, { "content": "Message 2", "messageSent": "2020-05-09" }, { "content": "Message 3", "messageSent": "2020-05-08" } ] }, { "conversationId": "1", "conversationTitle": "title 3", "messages": [ { "content": "Message 1", "messageSent": "2020-05-15" } ] }];

var result = data.map(({messages, ...rest})=>{messages = messages.sort((a,b)=> new Date(b.messageSent) - new Date(a.messageSent)); return {messages, ...rest}});

var sortedResult = result.sort((a,b)=>new Date(b.messages[0].messageSent)- new Date(a.messages[0].messageSent));

console.log(sortedResult);
```